# what is a negative 17 in hexadecimal value

Tags: binary, twos-complement, number-systems

I am a little bit confused in converting -17 into hex.
I know that 17 in hex is 11h but answer is in weird form.
-17= 17=11h

Answer is 0ffefh. I don't understand how this is done. can anyone show me the steps 
thanks.

Comment: Invert all the bits, then add one. Alternatively, you can first subtract one, then invert all the bits.

Comment: 0000 0000 0000 0011 complement is   1111 1111 1111 1101

Comment: however this result would be. 1111 1111 1111 1101 = FFFD

Comment: HOW CAN I GET 0FFEFH?

Comment: You have 11h, so 0000 0000 0001 0001, complement is 1111 1111 1110 1110, add one to get the result you observe

Comment: The concept is explained here http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Two's_complement#Why_it_works

Comment: negative 17 in hex is negative 11h

Comment: negative 17 in **twos complement** is something else people have described

Comment: -26 = 1Ah=? concept is not clear for me yet..

Comment: 1Ah = 0000 0000 0001 0010 = 1111 1111 1110 1110 =ffee i am getting wrong result. correct answer is. 0ffffffe6h

Comment: 1Ah is 0001 1010, try it with that

Comment: yea rite..can you explain me how you did it. I was thinking like each hexadecimal value is four bits. 1 = 0001 and A = 0010 i am justing adding zeros in front of hexadecimal characters but thats wrong. Could you explain it pls.. thanks

Comment: i got it anyway thanks, i have decimal 10 to binary..

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is suited for [math.se]

Answer (score 0):

> I don't think the question has anything to do with masm. Just a little dealing with binary numbers.

Since, you've already arrived at **17 = 11H**, let's proceed from there. Following 2's complement scheme/representation, **11H** is **0001 0001B** (just taking one byte). Since the first 8 bits are all `0`s, they'll result in `FF` after we're done.

**0001 0001B** give you on complementing every bit -> **1110 1110B**. Adding one to this result will yield: **1110 1111B** which in hexadecimal is **`EF`**.

Thus, the 2 byte representation becomes **`0xFFEFH`**